# JavaCV convertToIplImage return NULL

Tags: android, opencv, ffmpeg, video-processing, javacv

In JavaCV used in Android,while converting Frame to IplImage for applying color effect on video,we are NullPointerException.NPE is only encountered for some of the Frames in the Video.

```
...
while (true) {
   Log.d("JAVA_CV", "Counting . . . " + count);
   Frame original_frame = ffg.grab();
    if (original_frame == null) {

                    Log.d("JAVA_CV", "original_frame is NULL at" + count);
                    break;
                } else {
                    Log.d("JAVA_CV", "original_frame is NOT_NULL at" + count);
                    if (converter == null) {
                        Log.d("JAVA_CV", "converter is null at position" +count);
                        continue;

                    }
                    opencv_core.IplImage frame1 = null;
                    if (original_frame != null) {
                        frame1 = converter.convertToIplImage(original_frame);
                    } else {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (frame1 == null) {
                        Log.d("JAVA_CV", "frame1 is NULL at" + count);
                    } else {

                        if (!frame1.isNull() && original_frame.image != null) {


                            int width = frame1.width();
                            int height = frame1.height();
                            int channel = frame1.nChannels();
                            opencv_core.IplImage frame2 = opencv_core.IplImage.create(width, height, opencv_core.IPL_DEPTH_8U, channel);
                            if (frame2 == null)
                                continue;
                            opencv_core.cvCopy(frame1, frame2);
                            opencv_core.IplImage frame3 = opencv_core.IplImage.create(width, height, opencv_core.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
                            if (frame3 == null)
                                continue;
                            opencv_imgproc.cvCvtColor(frame2, frame3, opencv_imgproc.CV_BGRA2GRAY);

                            Log.d("JAVA_CV", "frame1 is NOT_NULL at" + count + " Height " + frame1.height());
                            Frame resultFrame = converter.convert(frame3);
                            if (resultFrame == null)
                                continue;
                            recorder.record(resultFrame);
                            frame1.release();
                            frame2.release();
                            frame3.release();
                            original_frame = null;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                count++;
            }
 ...
```

The Exception stack is here :

```
06-20 12:00:57.664  30245-30245/com.appxperts.opencvfirstapp W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException: This pointer address is NULL.
06-20 12:00:57.664  30245-30245/com.appxperts.opencvfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core$IplImage.width(Native Method)
06-20 12:00:57.664  30245-30245/com.appxperts.opencvfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at org.bytedeco.javacv.OpenCVFrameConverter.isEqual(OpenCVFrameConverter.java:75)
06-20 12:00:57.664  30245-30245/com.appxperts.opencvfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at org.bytedeco.javacv.OpenCVFrameConverter.convertToIplImage(OpenCVFrameConverter.java:85)
06-20 12:00:57.664  30245-30245/com.appxperts.opencvfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at org.bytedeco.javacv.OpenCVFrameConverter$ToIplImage.convert(OpenCVFrameConverter.java:41)
06-20 12:00:57.664  30245-30245/com.appxperts.opencvfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at com.appxperts.opencvfirstapp.MainActivitySecond.kaamdg(MainActivitySecond.java:161)
06-20 12:00:57.664  30245-30245/com.appxperts.opencvfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at com.appxperts.opencvfirstapp.MainActivitySecond$1.onClick(MainActivitySecond.java:62)
06-20 12:00:57.665  30245-30245/com.appxperts.opencvfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
06-20 12:00:57.665  30245-30245/com.appxperts.opencvfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18789)
06-20 12:00:57.665  30245-30245/com.appxperts.opencvfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
06-20 12:00:57.665  30245-30245/com.appxperts.opencvfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
06-20 12:00:57.665  30245-30245/com.appxperts.opencvfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)`enter code here`
06-20 12:00:57.665  30245-30245/com.appxperts.opencvfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
06-20 12:00:57.665  30245-30245/com.appxperts.opencvfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 12:00:57.665  30245-30245/com.appxperts.opencvfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-20 12:00:57.665  30245-30245/com.appxperts.opencvfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
06-20 12:00:57.665  30245-30245/com.appxperts.opencvfirstapp W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
```